# php change link to submit button

Tags: php, jquery, hyperlink, submit

I have this jquery script that refreshes a div tag on my page:

```
$(function() {

   $(".loadlink").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $("#result").load($(this).attr("href"));
   });

});
```

A link click activates it, but I want to change it to a button. Currently I have:

```
<a class="loadlink" href="crimes_result.php?id=<? echo $id ?>">do job<a>
```

Instead I want a submit button, like: (this doesnt work-doesn't send the id)

```
<input type="submit" class="loadlink" value=" do job " onClick="location.href='crimes2.php?id=<? echo $id ?>';this.disabled=true;">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you just style your link to look like a button?

Comment: What does javascript console say? + It should be `window.location.href`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leverage the data attribute and jQuery's data method. I think this is what you are trying to do.

html

```
<input type="submit" class="loadlink" data-url="crimes2.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>" />
```

javasript

```
$(function() {
   $(".loadlink").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $("#result").load($(this).data('url'));
   });
});
```

Comment: Good call. I'd just use type="button" instead of "submit" and do-away with the event.preventDefault().

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
<input type="submit" class="loadlink" value=" do job " onClick="loadlink('crimes2.php?id=<? echo $id ?>'); this.disabled=true;">
```

And JavaScript

```
function loadlink(href)
{
    $("#result").load(href);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the URL as a `data-attribute` in your button markup and read it like this in your JS:

```
$(function() {

   $(".loadlink").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $("#result").load($(this).attr("data-href"));
      this.disabled = true;
   });

});
```

This requires your button to look more like this:

```
<input type="submit" class="loadlink" value=" do job " data-href="crimes2.php?id=<? echo $id ?>';">
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working, is that the submit button does not have a `href` attribute.

You need to add the value you want to go to (the url) to the button and change your javascript accordingly or just change the link to make it look like a button.

Answer (score 0):

use a hidden field which will store the url to load:

```
<input type="hidden" name="myUrl" value="crimes_result.php?id=<? echo $id ?>" />
```

and use the javascript:

```
$(function() {

   $(".loadlink").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $("#result").load($('input[name=myUrl]').val());
   });

});
```